# Python ignoring %s placeholder

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, nessus

I'm trying to check if information is in a dictionary, and if so write to an Excel spreadsheet. However, the information I am checking for is subjective. I've tried using %s as a place holder but Python seems to ignore it, or believes the statement isn't true. No syntax errors come up. Can someone point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried using %d, but it ignored that as well. I was using a list before and switched to a dictionary, but that did not remedy the problem. If I specify a specific number it works, but not wight he placeholder %s.

Comment: `"%s" in hostids.values() == True` does *not* mean what you think it does.

Comment: I'm somewhat new. What does it mean?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. However, you *cannot* use string formatting syntax to test containment. What are you trying to test for here? If a value is not empty?

Comment: In other words, what made you think string formatting syntax could be used this way?

Comment: I must have misunderstood some advice/forum documentation I read. What I'm trying to test for: The values in the hostids dictionary is subjective, and grabs its information from a nessus scan. Therefore, hostids values will change every time other servers are scanned. I don't know what the hostids values are prior to scanning. I'm trying to tell Python- Whatever the hostids are, if their pluginids == "20007" then write to Excel.

Comment: That's still not clear to me; your `hostids` dictionary contains `host` values, whatever they are. Under what circumstances do you want those values to trigger your test?

Comment: If there are any values at all in the hostids dictionary, and their pluginids are "20007", then write to Excel. The values can be anything at all.

Comment: And *how do you know* if their `pluginids` are `'20007'`?

Comment: If hostids.values() > 0  worked. You made a lightbulb go off in my head. Now my only problem is that it only returns one of the hostids. It should return all of them that have pluginids of "20007".

Comment: @JustinBaxtron: I don't understand how you are using the word "subjective". Either you're using it wrong, or you're using it in an extremely technical way (perhaps relating to grammar or linguistics?) that isn't helping in the context of your problem. It's certainly not a common programming term. In "plain English" it means "based on opinion rather than fact".

Comment: You're right. A better way to say it would be: "A value that varies." A value that depends on another outcome, that outcome being the IP address of the server the script scans. Those IP addresses fill the values of the hostids dictionary.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters: I know the pluginids are '20007' because those values are static. The pluginid '20007' is a vulnerability id that comes up, if that specific server has the vulnerability definition assigned to '20007'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very basic "because there is no such syntax in python"

```
if "%s" in X:
    foo()
```

simply means "do foo() if the string '%s' is an element of collection X". So if

```
X = [ '%s', 'koala', 100 ]
```

then it will be true, but it has nothing to do with "placeholder" meaning of %s.

Comment: If I have a subjective value, then how can I tell Python to do something? I don't know what the value in the dictionary will be prior, because the values are only placed in after a nessus scan. How can I tell Python- Whatever the values inside hostids, write to Excel?

Comment: what do you mean by "subjective value", you seem to use this word in some extremely odd sense

Comment: A value that varies. A value that depends on the outcome of something else- Something that isn't predetermined.

Comment: there is no such thing. Variable in python, or any other language, has exactly one value in a given time moment. it does not matter whether it will change over time or not. You have to write down the exact condition that has to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'subjective value', it seems like you just want to know how to check if anything is in your hostids dict. for that, just use "if dict":

```
if hostids:
    <your code>
```